# How do you unit test code that generates or uses shell commands?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, shell, rspec

I'm writing a Ruby library that will automate some shell commands. The commands will depend on quite a complex set of business logic.

I want to unit test the code that generates those shell commands. I'm not sure how would I do that; I don't care much about the exact text of the commands, but I want to make sure the commands are affected by logic - which is of course the purpose of the unit tests.

My current idea is to encapsulate the command generation into very thin template-like objects (or just templates), and have logic code call those objects when it needs to produce a shell command, and then I can check that logic code calls expected methods on the template code. This still leaves the template code untested, but that's not as important as verifying the logic. Basically

```
class DirectoryMaker
  def initialize(generator)
    @generator = generator
  end
  def make_directory(name)
    if name=='baz'
      raise 'YOURE NOT ALLOWED TO DO THAT'
    else
      @generator.mkdir(name)
    end
  end
end

describe DirectoryMaker do
  it 'should produce a mkdir command' do 
    generator = double('Generator')
    generator.should_receive('mkdir').with('foo').and_return('')

    described_class.new(generator).make_directory('foo')
  end

  it 'should raise an exception when passed baz as a name' do
    expect {
      described_class.new(double('Generator')).make_directory('baz')
    }.to raise_error
  end
end
```

Ah, it seems I've answered my question, but if you have better suggestions I'd be happy to hear them.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure i understand you correctly.
yes you can make the thin layer that is an abstraction of your console output (model). you can test if your logic (controller) produces correct objects from this abstraction layer. and you can test if your templates renders correct shell output from the model (view). but what for? do you really need the full MVC pattern here?
you have your logic that should produce an output - a string. why can't you just test if some input parameters produce desired strings?